# Projeto Maven modular com Java10 modular não encontra os modulo java

Tags: maven, java-9

Estou adaptando o exercicio do livro "Java 9 - Interativo, reativo e modularizado - autor Rodrigo Turini" para um projeto maven modular com java 10 modular. 
Porem ao executar não esta encontrando os os modulos java do projeto

```
~/AmbienteDeDesenvolvimento/Projetos/Cursos/Java9/bookstore $ java -jar app/target/app-1.0.0.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: br/com/casadocodigo/http/Books
    at br.com.casadocodigo.MainMavenModulo.main(MainMavenModulo.java:17)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: br.com.casadocodigo.http.Books
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:190)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
    ... 1 more
```

**pom do projeto pai**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>br.com.casadocodigo</groupId>
  <artifactId>bookstore</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>



  <modules>

    <module>domain</module>
    <module>http</module>
    <module>nf</module>
    <module>app</module>

  </modules>

  <properties>
    <java.version>10</java.version>
    <start-class>br.com.casadocodigo.MainModulo</start-class>
    <maven-compiler-pluging.version>3.7.0</maven-compiler-pluging.version>
    <start-class>br.com.casadocodigo.MainMavenModulo</start-class>
  </properties>


  <build>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-compiler-pluging.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>10</source>
                <target>10</target>
                <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>

            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
                    <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
                    <version>6.1.1</version> 
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>3.0.2</version>
              <configuration>
                <archive>
                  <manifest>
                    <mainClass>${start-class}</mainClass>
                  </manifest>
               </archive>
             </configuration>
        </plugin>

     </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

**pom do projeto domain**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
    <groupId>br.com.casadocodigo</groupId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <artifactId>bookstore</artifactId>
  </parent>

  <artifactId>domain</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

</project>
```

**pom do projeto http**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
    <groupId>br.com.casadocodigo</groupId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <artifactId>bookstore</artifactId>
  </parent>

  <artifactId>http</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>br.com.casadocodigo</groupId>
        <artifactId>domain</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>   

</project>
```

**pom do projeto nf**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
    <groupId>br.com.casadocodigo</groupId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <artifactId>bookstore</artifactId>
  </parent>

  <artifactId>nf</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>br.com.casadocodigo</groupId>
        <artifactId>domain</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

</project>
```

**pom do projeto app**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
    <groupId>br.com.casadocodigo</groupId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <artifactId>bookstore</artifactId>
  </parent>

  <artifactId>app</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>br.com.casadocodigo</groupId>
        <artifactId>domain</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>br.com.casadocodigo</groupId>
        <artifactId>http</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>br.com.casadocodigo</groupId>
        <artifactId>nf</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

</project>
```

cada projeto tem seu module-info.java
Segue abaixo.

**module-info domain**

```
module domain {
    exports br.com.casadocodigo.domain;
}
```

**module-info http**

```
module http {
    exports br.com.casadocodigo.http;

    requires domain;
    requires jdk.incubator.httpclient;
}
```

**module-info nf**

```
module nf {
    exports br.com.casadocodigo.service;
    exports br.com.casadocodigo.model;

    requires domain;
}
```

**module-info app**

```
module app {
    exports br.com.casadocodigo;

    requires domain;
    requires http;
    requires nf;
}
```

**continua**

Para quem quiser ver o codigo na integra, o mesmo esta no meu github
https://github.com/marcelosartor/Estudo-Java10_Modular-Com-Maven_Modular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A forma ideal de executar usando módulos (de acordo com o comando do java) é usar:

```
ou  java [options] -m <module>[/<mainclass>] [args...]
    java [options] --module <module>[/<mainclass>] [args...]
         (para executar a classe principal em um módulo)
```

Neste caso, coloquei todas as jars no mesmo diretório, e executei:

```
java --module-path /home/marcos/diretorio-com-todas-as-jars -m app/br.com.casadocodigo.MainMavenModulo
```

A opção `--module-path` define a localização dos módulos:

```
--module-path <caminho do módulo>...
              Uma lista separada por : de diretórios, cada um
              sendo um diretório de módulos.
```